# How do I get Spring to print out the bean definitions it is picking up via component scanning?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a spring app that is configured for Component Scanning, is there a flag or option that I can turn on that would cause spring to print out the fully qualified names of the classes that the spring framework scanner picks up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can print this by configuring logging category (assuming you are using log4j), set `org.springframework.context.annotation` at debug level.

Check `org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(String)`.

You can see the class is logging name of the classes at debug level. Verified in Spring 3.0.5 version.

Comment: Also `<logger name="org.springframework.core.io.support" level="debug"/>` can be useful